# Do Gerrit slaves accept http and https protocols for fetches?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a master Gerrit instance where i can fetch using https and ssh protocols.

I understand that Gerrit slaves doesn't support UI or gitweb, so will will Gerrit slaves support or accept fetches over https protocols or is only ssh supported?

Can someone help me with the config for enabling httpd on Gerrit slaves ?
When gerrit is started in slave mode, only sshd is started.

```
[container]
`slave = true`
```

As per https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/pgm-daemon.html, there i have tried enable-httpd but its not working. Can someone help me on where to set enable-httpd in the gerrit.config file?

Comment: Hi Marcelo could you please suggest for below post.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63788081/13810933

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK replication is done over SSH (it's also possible to use replication over the insecure GIT protocol) but you're able to clone/fetch the Gerrit slaves using either SSH or HTTP protocol the same way you do from the Gerrit master.